# If-Statement not running inside useEffect but running outside it - NextJs/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, use-effect

I am trying to move my if-statement [line 30] located in useFetchMovieGenreResults [inside the hooks folder] from outside my my useEffect to inside the useEffect. However when I do this, I am not receiving my expected output (an object), rather I receive the error below.

However, when I move my if-Statement outside of my useEffect I get my expected output after 2 renders.

So my question is,

1. why is it when I move my If-Statement inside my useEffect, I do'nt
   get back the console.log results but I would get them back when I would move my if-Statement.
2. How do I reduce the number of renders I need to get my my result to
   one render?

I have linked to the code sandbox of the problem below so that you could get a bigger picture of the problem and see the app in its entirety. However below that is an example of what I have compared to what I am looking for.

https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-frog-hr4nwd

**What I have and is working. Notice the If-Statement outside the useEffect**

```
import useFetchNavBarCatagories from "./useFetchNavBarCatagories";
import useSelectedGenreInfoExtractor from "./useSelectedGenreInfoExtractor";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    
export default function useFetchMovieGenreResults(genre) {
  const [mymoviegenreinfo, setMymoviegenreinfo] = useState();
  const [mymoviegenreinfofinal, setMymoviegenreinfofinal] = useState();

  const mymoviegenreobjects = useFetchNavBarCatagories();

  console.log("Checking if its reading", genre);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMymoviegenreinfo(mymoviegenreobjects);
  }, [mymoviegenreobjects]);


  if (mymoviegenreinfo?.genres?.length > 0) {
    //! The bottom maps the key's values {genre[]}. Basically removing the outter object
    var mappedvalues = Object.keys(mymoviegenreobjects).map(
      (e) => mymoviegenreobjects[e]
    );

    console.log("The latest testinggggggggggggggggggg", mappedvalues);

    const flatarrayofvalues = mappedvalues.flat();
    console.log("Finally flat", flatarrayofvalues);

    const filtteredarray = flatarrayofvalues.filter(
      (character) => character.name === genre
    );

    console.log("This is avangers two ID", filtteredarray[0].id);

    console.log("just a check", mymoviegenreinfo);
    console.log(
      "a check for lengthhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh",
      mymoviegenreinfo?.genres?.length
    );

    return mymoviegenreinfo;
  }
}
```

**What I am looking for.**

Notice the if-Statement is inside the useEffect. However when I do it like this, my if-statement never runs because none of my judging by the fact that my console.logs don't run even when my conditions for the if-statement are fulfilled.

```
    import useFetchNavBarCatagories from "./useFetchNavBarCatagories";
    import useSelectedGenreInfoExtractor from "./useSelectedGenreInfoExtractor";
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    
export default function useFetchMovieGenreResults(genre) {
  const [mymoviegenreinfo, setMymoviegenreinfo] = useState();
  const [mymoviegenreinfofinal, setMymoviegenreinfofinal] = useState();

  const mymoviegenreobjects = useFetchNavBarCatagories();

  console.log("Checking if its reading", genre);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMymoviegenreinfo(
      mymoviegenreobjects,
      console.log("This is my infoooooo from the setstae", mymoviegenreinfo)
    );
    if (mymoviegenreinfo?.genres?.length > 0) {
      //! The bottom maps the key's values {genre[]}. Basically removing the outter object
      var mappedvalues = Object.keys(mymoviegenreobjects).map(
        (e) => mymoviegenreobjects[e]
      );

      console.log("I said HELLLLO0000");

      console.log("The latest testinggggggggggggggggggg", mappedvalues);

      const flatarrayofvalues = mappedvalues.flat();
      console.log("Finally flat", flatarrayofvalues);

      const filtteredarray = flatarrayofvalues.filter(
        (character) => character.name === genre
      );

      console.log("This is avangers two ID", filtteredarray[0].id);

      console.log("just a check", mymoviegenreinfo);
      console.log(
        "a check for lengthhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh",
        mymoviegenreinfo?.genres?.length
      );
      setMymoviegenreinfofinal(filtteredarray);
      console.log(filtteredarray);
    }
  }, [mymoviegenreobjects]);

  return mymoviegenreinfo;
   }
```

Comment: You are calling `setMymoviegenreinfo(mymoviegenreobjects);` inside useEffect with `mymoviegenreobjects` dependency. Its resulting in infinite loop

Comment: @Inder So why does it work fine in when I remove my if-Statement and put it outside the useEffect but if I keep the dependencies and settting of the state the same as you've mentioned? I simply want the same output of my if-Statement if I put it inside my useEffect. Also, I do not get an infinite loop error.  Mind elaborating what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are putting if statement wrong place you can have multiple useEffect()  in  react so you can put that code another one or inside useEffect() after `setMymoviegenreinfo(mymoviegenreobjects);`
inside the fat arrow function body.

Comment: So you are suggesting putting the if-Statement inside another useEffect which would be located after the first one? Why cant i just put it in the same useEffect?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a separate state for a computed object, use `useMemo`. Don't use state in the same function you assign using set, as it will cause an unresolved loop.

```
    const mymoviegenreinfofinal = useMemo(() => {
    if (mymoviegenreinfo?.genres?.length > 0) {
      var mappedvalues = Object.keys(mymoviegenreinfo).map(
        (e) => mymoviegenreinfo[e]
      );

      const flatarrayofvalues = mappedvalues.flat();

      const filtteredarray = flatarrayofvalues.filter(
        (character) => character.name === genre
      );

      return filtteredarray;
    }, [mymoviegenreinfo])
```